# Clone an instance of a class (Display Object)

Tags: actionscript-3, clone

I have a collection of movieclips, I would like to create a clone (a new instance) of a instance everytime I create a new object.

For example

```
var s:Star = new Star(); // star-shaped movielcip
addChild(s);
// then I want to duplicate an instance of s and add it beside s
```

For an example like above, it's simple enough to create a new instance with a different name and just add it to the display list. But I have a list of objects I would like to clone as a group...?

Comment: You could hold your 'template' objects in an array, and then loop over the array and create new objects, using the template object from the array to initialize whatever properties you need to on the new object. Does that make sense?  It kind of depends on how many / what properties you want 'cloned'.  Let me know if you're interested in a code sample.

Comment: a code sample would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moses' solution is correct. What is the purpose of the clone, where you wouldn't need to know the name of the clone to reference it?

One option is you could create an array to store your references in so you don't need to explicitly name them. Using moses' code...

```
var clones:Array = new Array();
for each (var star:Star in [s, s2, s3, s4, s5]) {
    clones.push(clone(star));
}
trace(clones.length);   // 5
```

This will result in an array that holds 5 cloned stars. It takes the least amount of code but it's up to you to make sure you know which star is which afterwards.

Comment: This is basically the same thing I would have sent you - except that this is even a little nicer.  HotN and moses are right - I'd go with their solution.

Answer (score 2):

Belowed code is very famous for cloning the objects. It's deepest and dynamic.

```
...
    function clone(orjObj:Object):Object {
        var copyObj:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        copyObj.writeObject(orjObj);
        copyObj.position = 0;
        return(copyObj.readObject());
    }

    var s2:Star = clone(s);
    s2.x = s.x + s.width;
    s2.y = s.y;
    addChild(s2);
```

Comment: This is good but I'm trying to create a new instance without having to resort to creating new instance names...

Comment: Your clone method doesn't work with DisplayObject instances. It just works with simple value objects. You can only serialize AMF compilant objects to a ByteArray.